# Remove/hide selected layer and display new layer after click on button

Tags: javascript, layers, select, list, remove

I´m trying to create two drop-down lists:

```
                    <select id= "select1">
                        <option value="layer1">layer 1</option>
                        <option value="layer2">layer 2</option>                         
                    </select>
                    <select id="select2">
                        <option value="_sample1">sample 1</option>
                        <option value="_sample2">sample 2</option>                          
                    </select>
                     <button id="testing">Try it</button>
```

I want to display map service with the help of values from these drop-down lists:

```
on(dom.byId("testing"), "click", myFunc);

function myFunc() {   
    var sum = document.getElementById("select1").value + document.getElementById("select2").value;
    var jprlLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(urlPrefix + "blabla/" + sum + "/MapServer", {
        "id": "jprlLayer",
        "opacity": 0.8
    });     
    mainMap.addLayer(jprlLayer);
    mainMap.reorderLayer(jprlLayer, 3);  
};
```

When I select values from lists and click on the button, the layer with specific id is displayed in the map. But when I want to select other values and click on the button again, it´s still showed the first layer instead of new layer according to newly selected values from lists. Can someone help me with this situation or advice me how to resolve this ? I need to remove actually showed layer and add new layer with newly selected values. Sum of values represents id of map services.

Comment: That is probably because you are creating the new layer with the same id. I would actually create & add the 2 layers at Map Initialization, and on the button click, toggle the visibility as required.

Comment: give up coding is hard...so GIVE UP.